# Is there a better way to calculate loss for multi-task DNN modeling?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, multitasking, loss, mse

Suppose there are over one thousand tasks in the multi-task deep learning. More than a thousand columns of labels. Each task (column) has a specific weight in this case. It would take such long time to loop over each task to calculate the sum of loss using the following code snippet.

```
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
```

```
outputs = model(inputs)
loss = torch.tensor(0.0).to(device)
for j, w in enumerate(weights):
    # mask keeping labeled molecules for each task
    mask = labels[:, j] >= 0.0
    if len(labels[:, j][mask]) != 0:
        # the loss is the sum of each task/target loss.
        # there are labeled samples for this task, so we add it's loss
        loss += criterion(outputs[j][mask], labels[:, j][mask].view(-1, 1)) * w
```

This dataset was quite small. The dataset has 10K rows and 1024 columns and the labels are a 10K * 160 sparse matrix. Each of those 160 columns is one task. Batch size is 32.  Below are the shapes of outputs, labels, weights:

```
len(outputs[0]), len(outputs)
(32, 160)
weights.shape
torch.Size([160])
labels.shape
torch.Size([32, 160])
```

But what I really want to try is one dataset which has over 1M rows and 1024 features and over 10K labels. The labels are sparse of course.

```
**update**
Thanks for you suggestions and code, Shai. I modified the code a little bit as follows, but the loss was the same as your code.
```

```
all_out = torch.cat(outputs).view(len(outputs), -1).T
all_mask = labels != -100.0
err = (all_out - labels) ** 2  # raw L2 
err = all_mask * err  # mask only the relevant entries in the err
mask_nums = all_mask.sum(axis=0)
err = err * weights[None, :]  # weight each task
err = err / mask_nums[None, :]
err[err != err] = torch.tensor([0.0], requires_grad=True).to(device) # replace nan to 0.0
loss = err.sum()
```

```
A newly raised question is the loss can't get back propagated. Only the loss of the first batch was calculated. The following batches got a loss of 0.0.

Epoch: [1/20], Step: [1/316], Loss: 4.702103614807129
Epoch: [1/20], Step: [2/316], Loss: 0.0
Epoch: [1/20], Step: [3/316], Loss: 0.0
Epoch: [1/20], Step: [4/316], Loss: 0.0
Epoch: [1/20], Step: [5/316], Loss: 0.0
The loss was 0 and outputs was 32* 160 of nan after the first batch.
```

Comment: what are the `shape`s  of `outputs`, `labels` and `weights`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The question was updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is your loss different than:

```py
all_out = torch.cat([o_[:, None] for o_ in outputs], dim=1)  # all_out has shape 32x160
all_mask = labels >= 0

err = (all_out - labels) ** 2  # raw L2 
err = all_mask * err  # mask only the relevant entries in the err
err = err * weights[None, :]  # weight each task
err = err.sum()
```

There might be a slight issue here with the summation - you might need to weight by the number of `1`s in each column of `all_mask`.

Comment: ``` def MSELoss2(outputs, labels, weights):
 #This one works perfectly
    all_out = torch.cat(outputs).view(len(outputs), -1).T
    all_mask = labels != -100.0
    mask_nums = all_mask.sum(axis=0)
    err = (all_out - labels) ** 2  # raw L2 
    err = err * weights[None, :]  # weight each task
    err = err / mask_nums[None, :]
    return torch.sum(err[all_mask]) ```

Comment: @user7725010 please do not post code in comments. Edit your question instead

Answer (score 0):

THanks, Shai. I finally figured it out. Here is the custom function worked well. I'm doing regression and -100 was used for mask in this case.

```
def MSELoss2(outputs, labels, weights):
    #This one works perfectly
    all_out = torch.cat(outputs).view(len(outputs), -1).T
    all_mask = labels != -100.0
    mask_nums = all_mask.sum(axis=0)
    err = (all_out - labels) ** 2  # raw L2 
    err = err * weights[None, :]  # weight each task
    err = err / mask_nums[None, :]
    return torch.sum(err[all_mask])
```